# AWS - Separate Disk Partitions on Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, partition, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to find the best practice way for separation of the operating system files from user files. I want to divide my new Instance (on creation) hard disk into multiple partitions (for better performance and security).

How do I make sure the following filesystems are mounted on separate partitions in c4.xlarge instance, Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type:

Separate partitions for:

```
/usr
/var
/tmp
/boot
/home
Separate partition for Apache
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

There's actually one compelling reason not to split up your partitions in EC2:

> ...a baseline performance of 3 IOPS/GiB...

General purpose SSD volumes -- which tend to offer the best price/performance value -- can handle more I/O operations per second, the larger they are.

> General Purpose (SSD) volume performance is governed by volume size, which dictates the baseline performance level of the volume and how quickly it accumulates I/O credits; larger volumes have higher baseline performance levels and accumulate I/O credits faster.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html#EBSVolumeTypes_gp2

The larger an individual *volume* is, the better it performs.  This is one of the significant differences between cloud servers (at least in EC2) and physical ones.  Having these different filesystems on different disks intuitively implies improved performance, but it turns out to be exactly the opposite.  One large volume performs better than two of half the size, unless by some chance your workload is evenly spread across the two... which is unlikely.

If your multiple partitions are, instead, on the same volume, that removes the performance concern, but then there's little point in multiple partitions on the same volume, since that tends to eventually leave you with stranded free space on one partition while you're crunched for space on another.

Granted, you can pay a premium for provisioned IOPS but it seems only sensible not to work "against" the system.

When you do a "new install" on EC2, of course, you're not "installing" the OS in the conventional sense, you're cloning a base installation that's been made by or for the particular Linux distro... and you can set up each new VM from this baseline, or you can create your own baseline image (Amazon Machine Image/AMI) which contains a little bit of metadata and pointers to disk volume snapshots which will be cloned into new volumes to build each new machine... which means you have to pay to store snapshots with the partitioning and size you want... or resize them after you build each machine.  On the other hand, if you use a single filesystem, the master image can be small and automatically grow the filesystem on first boot to fill the disk to whatever size that particular machine has been provisioned to be.

Granted, this is partially a matter of opinion, but my standard practice is to use a single filesystem *except* in cases where I have a single purpose that requires significant storage, such as a database or an application needing an unusually large temporary/working directory.  (I have a couple of systems with 2TB of temp space -- which they need -- and a 20GB root/boot/everything-else disk volume...no point in storing a 2TB snapshot for cloning the machines.)

So, let's say you're not persuaded.  How do you do what you asked?  By hand.

You'll need 2 instances, in the same availability zone. Do a base install on the first one.  You'll be using it temporarily.  Launch the second one,  with all the disk volumes you intend to attach, for whatever purposes.  Install the OS, then note of the volume to device mappings.  Then stop the second instance, detach all the volumes, and attach them to the first one, which is already running.  Format the extra disks as desired (you *can* partition them, but it isn't necessary -- using the entire block device without a partition table, e.g. `/dev/xvdf` instead of `/dev/xvdf1` makes it much easier to expand the filesystem later, mount all your file systems, rearrange your files, edit `/etc/fstab` (not then one on `/etc` on the temporary instance, but rather the one on the root volume you've attached elsewhere on your temporary instance) so that the extra filesystems will get mounted in the right place from the right volume then unmount all the filesystems,  detach the volumes, reattach them in the correct order, and start it back up.

Once you've verified that it boots, and everything is in the right place, make an AMI from it, and your clone your future machines from there, and you'll have your disk volumes and filesystems and (optionally) partitions the way you want them.  If it doesn't, you may end up having to check the console log, and detaching the volumes and hooking them back up to the temporary machine until you find what you missed... but in principle, this is all perfectly viable and perhaps more straightforward than it sounds.  A little bit, anyway.

Comment: Thanks Michael. What do you think about separate partitions for Apache, MySQL.

Comment: I don't see any solid reasons for additional partitions on  a single EBS volume, since it is so trivial to resize for more space if you need it if you don't.  For MySQL I do typically use a separate filesystem on a separate volume, except for smaller data sets, since that makes a lot of things easier, like setting up replication slaves.  For Apache, probably not unless you have a huge amount of content, in which case S3 is often a better choice.  MySQL and Apache should not be on the same machine in production, since [things can get ugly under load](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25083/11651).